# Rails: I'm getting a strange "NoMethodError" when I upload files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, upload

I'm pretty new to Rails and I can't seem to figure this one out. I have a basic CRUD called projects, where people can submit new projects. I also made it so they can upload files if they choose to do so. Now the files upload perfectly fine, but the problem is if the user doesn't upload a file I get this error. `undefined method 'original_filename' for nil:NilClass` on this line of code here `File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|`

Now I'm a little stumped, because do I not need `original_filename`? It works when a file is added, but when there is no file it doesn't...

projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def show


  end

  def new
    @projects = Project.new

  end

  def create #no view
    @projects = Project.new(project_params)
    uploaded_io = params[:doc]
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
          file.write(uploaded_io.read)
    end
    if @projects.save
      redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project was sent!"
    else 
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @projects = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update #no view
    @projects = Project.find(params[:id])

    if @projects.update_attributes(project_params)
      redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project has been updated."
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy #no view
    @projects = Project.find(params[:id])
    @projects.destroy
    redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project has been deleted."
  end

  private
  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description)
  end


end
```

(projects) _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@projects, :html => { :multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <%= label_tag :doc, 'Files (optional)' %>
    <%= file_field_tag :doc %>

    <br>

    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Submit Project", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And then I also set up an `uploads` folder within my `public` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make these changes:

```
 def create #no view
    @projects = Project.new(project_params)
    uploaded_io = params[:doc]
    if uploaded_io.present?
      File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
          file.write(uploaded_io.read)
      end
    end
    if @projects.save
      redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project was sent!"
    else 
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

This will check if the doc exists then only it will try to open it or else it would just skip it and you will not get the error. When there is no doc the value of `params[:doc]` is `nil`. So rails tries to do `nil.original_filename` which throws the error.

Comment: Thank you this worked! I thought it had something to do with an if/else but couldn't get it!